# How do I know how much bandwidth each computer uses?

Tags: windows, networking, bandwidth

I have two computers. I'd like to know if there's a program that shows the bandwidth consumption of each. Is that possible?

Sometimes my connection get very slow, but in the other computer, it's normal. Maybe the other computer is using too much of the bandwidth, that's why I need some program that can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First possibility is to use different Tools to monitor and analyze your bandwidth. Some of these tools are for example: [NetWorX](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) and [FreeMeter](http://miechu.pl/freemeter/). The First tool gives you an overview according to day, week, and month and apart from that it lets you export that data.
2. One other possibilty would depend on the fact if you are using a router and what kind of, because what you could do is to track your bandwidth usage at the router level, assuming you have your own router and access to it, like for example a AVM product like FRITZ!. There a even a bunch of routers which give such an opportunity.
3. You could check your bandwidth at Your ISP's Web Site, as for example ISP's like AT&T offer services like a "monitoring portal".